# Do a HTTP Post in Cypress without using a test

Tags: cypress

I have a Cypress test:

```js
describe('Create a session ', () => {
    it('creates a session', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `${Cypress.env('apiURL')}/api/v1/user/login/`,
            form: true,
            body: {
                email: Cypress.env('email'),
                password: Cypress.env('password'),
            },
        }).then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
            cy.task('setKey', response.body.data.key);
        });
    });
});
```

This POST returns some session data needed to create a dummy account:

```js
describe('Create a company ', () => {
    it('creates a company', () => {
        cy.task('getKey')
            .then((data: Key) => {
                key = data;
            })
            .then(() => {
                createNonce();
                cy.request({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: `${Cypress.env('apiURL')}/api/v1/cli/`,
                    headers: {
                        'X-Auth-Timestamp': epochTime(),
                        'X-Auth-Key': key.key,
                        'X-Auth-Nonce': nonce,
                        'X-Auth-Signature': createSignature(),
                    },
                    body: {
                        args: ['seeder', 'create', 'abc1'],
                    },
                }).then((response) => {
                    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
                    // TODO: we need some REST endpoints to return a JSON object instead of a string
                    data = JSON.parse(response.body.substring(response.body.indexOf('{')));
                    cy.task('setCompany', data);
                });
            });
    });
});
```

I'm not sure I need these functions to be tests since they don't test anything, but just do a POST request. Is it possible to maybe move the functionality into a cypress task?

Comment: May be this could help https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-request-and-cookies/#request-from-node

Answer (score 2):

You can add the post request in your commands file:

```
function postRequest() {
   cy.request({
                method: 'POST',
                url: `${Cypress.env('apiURL')}/api/v1/cli/`,
                headers: {
                    'X-Auth-Timestamp': epochTime(),
                    'X-Auth-Key': key.key,
                    'X-Auth-Nonce': nonce,
                    'X-Auth-Signature': createSignature(),
                },
                body: {
                    args: ['seeder', 'create', 'abc1'],
                },
            })
}

Cypress.Commands.add('postRequest', postRequest)
```

An assuming all the rest of your code is fine, and you want only to abstract the logic; then in your test you can invoke that command:

```
describe('Create a company ', () => {
it('creates a company', () => {
    cy.task('getKey')
        .then((data: Key) => {
            key = data;
        })
        .then(() => {
            createNonce();
            cy.postRequest().then((response) => {
                expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
                  
                data = JSON.parse(response.body.substring(response.body.indexOf('{')));
                cy.task('setCompany', data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move these into `before()` or `beforeEach()` so they will be separate from your tests.

```js
describe('Create a company ', () => {
    before(() => {
       cy.task('getKey')
            .then((data: Key) => {
                key = data;
            })
            .then(() => {
                createNonce();
                cy.request({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: `${Cypress.env('apiURL')}/api/v1/cli/`,
                    headers: {
                        'X-Auth-Timestamp': epochTime(),
                        'X-Auth-Key': key.key,
                        'X-Auth-Nonce': nonce,
                        'X-Auth-Signature': createSignature(),
                    },
                    body: {
                        args: ['seeder', 'create', 'abc1'],
                    },
                }).then((response) => {
                    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
                    // TODO: we need some REST endpoints to return a JSON object instead of a string
                    data = JSON.parse(response.body.substring(response.body.indexOf('{')));
                    cy.task('setCompany', data);
                });
            });
    })
    it('creates a company', () => {
      //test code  
    });
});
```